# uses of spring framework in java

Tags: java, spring

I have read that the main uses of spring is DI and AOP.

As far as i understand spring in 3 weeks , i feel that AOP can be done in aspectj
and DI is technique not specific to spring with API's.

so is i am missing anything. spring only creates beans.

is that it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read that the main uses of
>   spring is DI and AOP.

And the modules and libraries that come with both.  Spring is a three-legged stool, in my opinion.

> As far as i understand spring in 3
>   weeks , i feel that AOP can be done in
>   aspectj

Of course AOP can be done with AspectJ - as long as you don't mind byte code alterations.  You can also use Spring's original AOP, which uses proxies and is less invasive.

> and DI is technique not
>   specific to spring with API's.

I'm not sure I understand your point here.  The wording isn't very clear.  If your point is that DI can be done without Spring, then I'd say you are correct.

> so is i am missing anything. spring
>   only creates beans.

I'd say you're missing everything.

> is that it

What else do you want it to do?

What alternative do you prefer?

UPDATE:

I don't know about PHP, but there's a version of Spring for Python: Spring.py.  This suggests to me that you can certainly do both DI and AOP in Python.  I would say that they're possible in any language that's truly object-oriented.  The ideas of DI and AOP are like any other OO pattern: language agnostic.

Comment: i mean DI can be done without spring and AOP with ASPECTJ. beside these two what lese is done in spring which cant be done outside it

Comment: @Name: same question to you: what may be done in Java, that cannot be done outside it? So, what is the point in using Java?

Comment: @Name - Yes to Python, C#, C++.  I don't know about PHP.  I hear that there's an object-oriented version of PHP, but I'm ignorant of it and have no idea if run of the mill PHP developers use the OO features at all.

Comment: @Name - Anything that Spring can do is possible without Spring.  It represents one person's implementation, nothing more.  You sound like you're looking for either an excuse to not use Spring for Java or a statement that it's possible to do what Spring does in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is in my opinion a defacto standard when it comes to developing web applications/services, or even general application development.

It provides dependency injection as one of its strongpoints, to offer the conveniance of having all necessary tools in one package.

AoP on the other hand nicely integrates with Spring, but is in no way a fundamental reason to use spring. In fact, I dare to claim that alot of people probably don't explicitly (the underlying framework might still do it for you though). You can probably use spring a lifetime without having to explicitly use AoP.

Comment: "Standard when it comes to developing web servers"?  I love Spring, but this is either worded badly or simply not true.  AOP is very much at the heart of Spring.  If you're doing container managed transactions, you're using Spring AOP whether you know it or not.

Comment: Right, not my intention to be argumentative. Let's say this is my view of things and doesn't aim to reflect why everyone else use it.

Comment: But you don't write web servers in Spring.  You write web applications, but the app servers they run on are not developed in Spring.  Even the one that SpringSource themselves market is a variation on Tomcat.  It uses Spring, but it wasn't written from the ground up with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

It is a container and MVC web application framework as well. There is also OSGI support. Spring consists of many parts/modules, which can be integrated with other frameworks such as Hibernate.

http://www.springsource.org/about